# Question on injective envelopes

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, projective-module, injective-module, artinian

Let $A$ be an Artin algebra and let $\text{mod}(A)$ denote the category of finitely generated left $A$-modules.

> Let $S$ be a simple module in $\text{mod}(A)$ and let $\iota_S: S \rightarrow I(S)$ be the injective envelope of $S$. Then  the natural epimorphism $p: I(S) \rightarrow I(S)/\text{Im}(\iota_S)$ is irreducible.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to prove this. Can anybody help?

Comment: Probably just me wondering, but in what sense is the epimorphism supposed to be irreducible?

Comment: @rschwieb In http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~webb/oldteaching/Year19-20/Math8300Notes2019.pdf, irreducible morphisms are defined as follows: A morphism $g:X \to Y$ in a category is called irreducible if it has neither a left nor a right inverse and whenever $g = ts$, then $t$ either has a left inverse or $t$ has a right inverse.

Comment: @QiZhu Thanks! That's useful for me, at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose not. Then $p$ factors as
$$I(S)\xrightarrow{s}X\xrightarrow{t}I(S)/\operatorname{Im}(\iota_S),$$
where $s$ is not a split monomorphism.

Since $I(S)$ is injective, $s$ can not be a monomorphism, or it would be a split monomorphism. Since $\operatorname{Im}(\iota_S)$ is the unique simple submodule of $I(S)$, it must be contained in the kernel of $s$, and so $s$ factors through $p$: say $s=rp$ for some $r:I(S)/\operatorname{Im}(\iota_S)\to X$. So $p=ts=trp$, and so $tr$ is the identity map of $I(S)/\operatorname{Im}(\iota_S)$, since $p$ is surjective.

So $t$ is a split epimorphism.

Comment: By definition one also needs to show that $p$ is not a section nor a retraction, right? It is fairly easy to see that $p$ cannot be a section. But how does it follow that it is not a retraction?

Comment: @mathStudent If $p$ is a retraction then $I(S)\cong S\oplus I(S)/\operatorname{Im}(\iota_S)$, But $I(S)$ is indecomposable, so this can't happen unless $S=I(S)$ and so $ I(S)/\operatorname{Im}(\iota_S)=0$. You're right that in that one trivial case $p$ is not irreducible, since it is the zero map.